# Hide catch all voice commands

Tags: windows-phone-8, voice-recognition

I'm implementing voice commands on to my Windows Phone 8 application, I have a number of commands that use phrase lists.

To have a better UX I'm using a catch all command for each of them for instance the following commands.

```
<Command Name="OpenCategory">
  <Example>open category chores</Example>
  <ListenFor>[and] open category {CategoryName}</ListenFor>
  <ListenFor>[and] show [me] category {CategoryName}</ListenFor>
  <ListenFor>[and] display category {CategoryName}</ListenFor>
  <Feedback>Opening {CategoryName}...</Feedback>
  <Navigate Target="/Views/CategoryTasksView.xaml" />
</Command>

<Command Name="OpenCategoryUnknown">
  <Example>open category chores</Example>
  <ListenFor>[and] open category {*}</ListenFor>
  <ListenFor>[and] show [me] category {*}</ListenFor>
  <ListenFor>[and] display category {*}</ListenFor>
  <Feedback>Couldn't find that category...</Feedback>
  <Navigate Target="/Views/CategoryListView.xaml" />
</Command>
```

However the "What can I say?" UI ends up with duplicate examples and with five commands following this pattern it really ruins the example UI.

Is there any way to make certain commands to now show examples?